# Como salvar dados de um formulario no DB com CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Bom Dia

preciso de uma ajuda pois estou criando um formulario para salvar somente datas...e estou com problemas para criar esse codigo...por falta de experiencia mesmo...

a view já está criada com 4 campos para datas...
e ai no controller eu estou meio perdido.

Já debuguei a $dados e ela tras as informações no banco inseridas na marra...até ai tudo bem.
a parte comentada eu deixei para quando troxer as datas salvas e informar se deu certo ou não...

[image: tela campos com datas]

**Controller**

```
public function desligamentocliente()
{
    //$this->verifica_ausencia_dados($this->request->data['idCliente']);
    $this->loadModel( "DesligamentoCliente" );               

    $idCliente = ( isset( $this->request->params['pass'][0] ) ) ? $this->request->params['pass'][0] : 0;

    $dados = $this->DesligamentoCliente->find( "all", array( "conditions" => array("_esc_codigo" => $idCliente )));

    /*
    $dados == 1 ? $this->Desligamentos->DesligamentoCliente->save("data_financeiro", "data_fiscal", "data_contabil", "data_pessoal") : 

        $this->request->data['DesligamentosCliente']['data_financeiro'] = General::formata_data_mysql($this->request->data['DesligamentosCliente']['data_financeiro'] );
        $this->request->data['DesligamentosCliente']['data_fiscal']     = General::formata_data_mysql($this->request->data['DesligamentosCliente']['data_fiscal'] );
        $this->request->data['DesligamentosCliente']['data_contabil']   = General::formata_data_mysql($this->request->data['DesligamentosCliente']['data_contabil'] );
        $this->request->data['DesligamentosCliente']['data_pessoal']    = General::formata_data_mysql($this->request->data['DesligamentosCliente']['data_pessoal'] );


        if ($this->Desligamentos->desligamentocliente->updateAll( array("data_financeiro" => $data_financeiro, "data_fiscal" => $data_fiscal, "data_contabil" => $data_contabil, "data_pessoal" => $data_pessoal)
                                                                )
            ) {
            $msg = "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar as datas";

            if ($this->Desligamentos->desligamentocliente->save($this->request->data)) {
                $msg = "Datas salvas com sucesso";
                $class = "alert alert-success";
            }
        }

$this->Session->setFlash($msg, "alerta", array("class" => $class));
$this ->redirect("/clientes");
*/ }
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda... =)

Comment: Não entendi direito, ele esta salvando no banco, porém com as datas erradas? em que formato esta as suas datas na view (formato br? d/m/Y?)

Comment: Vou tentar explicar melhor @JefersonAssis 
oq eu estou com dificuldade é de mondar if...(ñ sei se é isso mesmo) que receba as datas informadas no formulario e salve elas no banco.
eu debuguei a variavel dados...praticamente do jeito que está..."print_r($dados); die()"
e ela me mostrou dados que eu inseri manualmente na tabela q ela deve receber.

Comment: Vou postar na resposta, talvez seja o que você precise

Comment: então oque eu preciso...de o codigo no controller receba esses dados do fomulario e salve eles no banco....e me mostre em cada campos a data informada...

Comment: Valeu @JefersonAssis...
muito agradecido =)

Comment: Respondi, verifica se te ajuda a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se esta vindo um post e resgatar os dados envido pelo formulário

Caso esteja usando o **CakePHP 3.0**, adicione no primeiro linha do seu `controller` após o `<?php`

> use Cake\I18n\Time;

```
if($this->request->is('post')):
    $data = $this->request->data;

    foreach($data['DesligamentosCliente'] as &$value):
        $value = Time::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d');
    endforeach;

    pr($data);
endif;
```